# Ruby cannot find gem (populator) even though it's installed

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am trying to work with the Populator gem. I just installed it, but Ruby is unable to load it. I have only one Ruby installation on my machine and it's Ruby 1.8.7. What can I do?

[This is the gem that doesn't get loaded](http://github.com/ryanb/populator).

Edit: Here is the trace out. I should have included this earlier.

```
Freenaut:bio-clinical newuser$ rake db:populate --trace
(in /Users/newuser/Dropbox/Sites/rails/bio-clinical)
** Invoke db:populate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:populate
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- populator
/Users/newuser/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
/Users/newuser/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
/Users/newuser/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
/Users/newuser/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:591:in `new_constants_in'
/Users/newuser/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
/Users/newuser/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
```

Comment: "What can I do?" -- Post the error message. My crystal ball is at the cleaners.

Comment: @jorg sorry about that. I amended my post with the error message.

Comment: What does `rake gems` tell you?

Comment: @zetetic: it says "Don't know how to build task 'gems'"

Answer (score 1):

To date the Populate plugin just does not support Rails 3.
See [the GitHub site](https://github.com/ryanb/populator) for current status.

This seems to be a really handy plugin, hopefully there will be Rails 3 support soon.

Answer (score 0):

Are you working with Rails or just Ruby?

Did you use

```
require 'rubygems'
```

before `require 'populator'`?

Comment: I'm working with Rails. It didn't make a difference when I added 'require "rubygems"' just now.